# Look and Feel for Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel, jtabbedpane

I am confused about look feel's reaction in java.

Initially I have used synthetica blue moon look and feel in my java swing application, It works fine for my application.

Later I have switched to jTatoo luna look and feel, It slows down the Jabbed pane operation(I have set mouse moved event in jtabbedpane, jtatoo look and feel slows this operation)

Does look and feel affect the component's event?